# Unambiguous alternative to the word "lower"?

Tags: word-usage

Higher is to lower as upper is to ... lower?

I asked a question on Quora about why the human voice has a lower volume limit. Like, you can't speak at as low of a loudness as you can whisper.

Here's one answer:

> A "lower volume limit" in comparison to WHAT? Can you be more specific, please?

I used "lower limit" to mean "the least you can go," but the answer understood it as a comparative adjective (as such in "A has a lower Stack Overflow reputation than B").

"Bottom limit" doesn't sound right. What're unambiguous alternatives to the word "lower" in this context?

Comment: *Lower* is the best antonym of both *higher* and *upper* that I can think of. It has multiple senses, I don't find it ambiguous in either context. The use of *lower* with *volume limit* is just fine. I suspect the problem was with the actual phrasing of your Quora question, not with *lower* itself. (Because I understand the request for clarification—and it's not because of the lack of a better antonym.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You describe your point perfectly with this:

> ... you can't speak at as low of a loudness as you can whisper.

But without seeing the full Quora question it's hard to know what the problem is with your description.  Perhaps you could leverage *minimum* and *maximum*?

> Why does the human voice have a minimum volume?  For example, you can whisper more quietly than you can speak using your normal voice.

Another option could be *softly*:

> Why can't one speak as softly as a whisper while still maintaining the sound of their voice?